# Dinamic Select hidden input

Tags: javascript

I hope to explain my problem well
I want to create a form that allows you to dynamically add selections and inputs
Select retrieve a odbc array
The form is this:

```
<form name="add_name" id="add_name">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
<tr>
<td>
<select name="name[]" id="category" class="form-control" width="300px"   onchange="aggiornaHidden(this)">
<option value="">Seleziona Ordine - Articolo</option>
<?php
 echo $popola
?>
</select>
<INPUT type="hidden" name="sel_value">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="sel_text">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="quantita[]" placeholder="Inserisci quantita" class="form-control name_list" />
</td>
<td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Aggiungi Riga</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

this is PHP code:

```
<?php
  $conto='2411000044';
  $dsn = 'iSeries';
    $connessione = odbc_connect("iSeries", "utente, "pwd", 2) or die        ("Impossibile Connettersi " . odbc_errormsg());

   if($conto==""){
     echo "impossibile trovare il codice artigiano....<br>";
   }
 else{
     $interrogazione ="SELECT A.tipo, A.numero, A.codice, A.descrizione, B.barcode FROM file1 A, file2 B WHERE (A.codice=B.codice1) AND a.fornitore='".trim($conto)."' ORDER BY A.codice, A.numero ASC";
  $risultato = odbc_exec($connessione, $interrogazione);
  while (odbc_fetch_row($risultato))
  {
   $popola .= '<option value="'.odbc_result($risultato,"tipo").'-'.odbc_result($risultato,"numero").'-'.trim(odbc_result($risultato,"codice")).'-'.trim(odbc_result($risultato,"barcode")).'">'.odbc_result($risultato,"tipo").' - '.odbc_result($risultato,"numero").' - '.odbc_result($risultato,"codice").' - '.odbc_result($risultato,"descrizione").'</option>';
  }
  }
  ?>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
  $('#add').click(function(){
   i++;
  $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><select name="name[]" id="category" class="form-control" width="300px" onchange="aggiornaHidden(this)"><option value="">Seleziona Ordine - Articolo</option><?php echo $popola?></select><INPUT type="hidden" name="sel_value"><INPUT type="hidden" name="sel_text"></td><td><input type="text" name="quantita[]" placeholder="Inserisci quantita" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
     var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
    });

   function aggiornaHidden(sel){
    var f = document.add_name;
   f.sel_value.value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
   f.sel_text.value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
   }
  </script>
```

The first selection successfully adds the value to the hidden input
After clicking on "Add Row" the second select is populated but choosing a different value the value of the hidden input remains blank
Where I wrong?
thanks

Comment: Your select box name is name[] not sel. So it will not work.